# Are Julia arrays homogeneous or not?

Tags: arrays, types, julia

On the one hand, if I have `x=[1,2,3]`, then I cannot add `"foo"` to `x`, but if I start with `x=[1,2,3,"foo"]`, then the union type is `Any`, and I can add whatever I want to my array. Is it correct to say that Julia arrays are homogeneous? Because I can just create array of `Any`.

Comment: They are both — by default Julia tries to create homogenous arrays, but if it cannot it will give you back a heterogeneous array.

Comment: Julia is stronly typed. A "heterogeneous" Julia array is just a homogeneous array of element type `Any`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia will by default restrict a given array to as specific an element type (eltype) as possible. However, julia has a special syntax to make an array with whatever eltype you like. So, to create an array with eltype `T`, you just write `T[x, y, z]` instead of `[x, y, z]`. For your example, this would be

```
julia> v = Any[1,2,3]
p3-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> push!(v, "foo")
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
  "foo"
```

The reason for this behaviour is that if we can restrict an array to be of a specific, concrete type, there are some major performance optimizations that can be made. If you have an array with eltype `Any`, then the contents cannot be densely packed in memory.